# How to scrape an article with beautifulSoup across different website in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape a webpage, using beautiful soup, but the response i got is not really what i wanted, this is the code below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://hajj.media.gov.sa/en/stories/hani-haider-about-3500-workers-working-24-7-to-sterilize-masjid-al-haram", headers={"user-Agent":"chrome/79.0.3945.88"})
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
value_raw=soup.find("body").get_text()
value_raw
```

**what i want to achieve is get all the articles of the webpage below**

Hani Haider, Official Spokesperson for General Presidency for the Affairs of the Two Holy Mosques, described various health preventive measures taken on various spots at the Holy Sites, to ensure the safety of pilgrims during 2020 exceptional Hajj season.

“One of the precautions taken by the General Presidency [for the Affairs of the Two Holy Mosques] Was allocating a number of doors for the entry of pilgrims and different doors for their exit” said Mr. Haidar.

The Official Spokesperson for General Presidency for the Affairs of the Two Holy Mosques said that these measures were taken: “So we can guarantee, by God’s will, that no congestion or crowding will take place.”

The General Presidency also recruited About 3,500 workers Who work 24/7 To sterilize Masjid al-Haram, as well as purify and apply fragrances to it. All fountains of the Zamzam well were also closed and replaced with sterilized bottles of Zamzam water Which are produced in accordance with the highest health standards.”

Ministry of Media closed his remarks saying: “We ask God Almighty to accept the pilgrims’ Hajj and religious duties, and to ensure their safe return to their families.”

Comment: try `value_raw=soup.find('div',{'class':"content-text"}).get_text()`

Answer (score 0):

extract by `class`:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    r = requests.get("https://hajj.media.gov.sa/en/stories/hani-haider-about-3500-workers-working-24-7-to-sterilize-masjid-al-haram", headers={"user-Agent":"chrome/79.0.3945.88"})
    c = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
    value_raw = soup.find("div", {"class": "content-text"}).get_text()
    print(value_raw)
```

or extract by html tag `<p>`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://hajj.media.gov.sa/en/stories/hani-haider-about-3500-workers-working-24-7-to-sterilize-masjid-al-haram", headers={"user-Agent":"chrome/79.0.3945.88"})
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
value_raw = soup.find_all("p")

for p in value_raw:
    print(p.text)
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but my concern when i passed another url from another website, it wont work, that is why i don't want to target any class, is there a way you can do it, highest i will have to clean up the content

Comment: Are you intend to scrape any website with a single script?